# Custom Metadata Type - Custom Field - Picklist Values Not editable after packaging

Tags: managed-package, package, configuration, custom-metadata

I'm currently trying to figure out why we're unable to edit Custom Metadata Custom Field Picklist Values after packaging in another org. From my understanding, I should be able to edit these existing packaged values if I select "subscriber editable" - the account I'm using to attempt to update these fields is a Sys Admin and I'm able to create new custom field mappings, and I'm also able to edit the custom field mappings themselves, just not the values. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Nope - had to create the picklist manually in each package and assign the api name to a custom setting

Comment: that sucks, I had to change the values in the xml and then create a new package version